# Maximum number of components in a Graph Containing $n$ vertices and $k$ edges

Tags: graph-theory

I know that in a Graph $G$ Containing  $n$ vertices and $k$ edges,$G$ will contain atleast $n-k$ components.

Explanation-:

> Graph containing $n$ vertices and $0$ edges will contain $n$ components.Each time adding an edge will **reduce** the component by 1.Thus $k$ edge will contain $n-k$ component.
>   This is the minimum number.

I am interested in finding the maximum number of component.please help me out !!!

Comment: By the way, this question considers only simple graphs, right?

Comment: @shn yes it is simple graph !

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In the worst case the edges are used to form a clique. Let $i$ be the smallest integer $\ge 1$ s.t. $\frac{i(i-1)}{2} \ge k$. There are $n-i+1$ connected components in that case, which is maximal posible.

Comment: Just beat me to it. +1

Answer (score 1):

The maximum number of components comes from using complete graphs. For instance, with two edges, you lose two components. With three edges, you can make a complete subgraph and lose no edges. The result is $n-l$ such that $l$ is the lowest integer satisfying $k\le \frac{l(l+1)}2$, where $k$ is the number of edges, $n$ is the number of nodes.